# How can I set one field to be less restricted in an Amplify GraphQL API schema?

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have the following schema for an amplify project using GraphQL API:

```
type SomeItem
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, delete, update] }
    ]
  ){
  id: ID!
  owner: String
  version: Int!
  text: String
  read: Boolean @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, delete] }])
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

What I want to be able to do is for only the Owner to create/update/delete every field.

I want to allow anybody to update the read field only.  I have tried the above to make the read field less restrictive but it's not working.  How can I make one field in the model less restrictive than the other fields?  Do I need to set an @auth for each field individually?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I also have similar queries but no luck

Comment: I couldn’t figure it out or get any help so moved on.